# Extract data from Json output using Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I wrote a Ansible playbook to retrieve the DNS entries from the Cloudflare platform. Before exporting the entries to a CSV file, I'm trying to capture the total records count. But no matter how I try, it is always displaying the `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED` error.

Following is my playbook:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Listing the cloudflare DNS records...
      uri:
        url: https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zoneid/dns_records?page=1&per_page=1&type=A
        method: GET
        headers:
          X-Auth-Email: "myemail@gmail.com"
          X-Auth-Key: "jvnnf345mnbhfgj5"
          Content-Type: "application/json"
      register: cloudflare_records

    - name: Displaying the records...
      debug:
        var: cloudflare_records
```

Above playbook is working as expected and displaying the following output:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
"cloudflare_records": {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_label": 1, 
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "cache_control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0", 
            "cf_ray": "4b64c01132-SIN", 
            "changed": false, 
            "connection": "close", 
            "content_type": "application/json", 
            "cookies": {
                "__cf_bm": "3852871f6e8f0ff02f410491f-1552383037-1800-Acq+ObfnSR8WRCVLvsYmprM61p3DayCFn9W12LhqPFpzKqVCUvi9oCxaYUhN9XfNgdEvZc3RTa79NxufrMv8aoU=", 
                "__cfduid": "dc8d780e98d213b61f1f1552383037"
            }, 
            "cookies_string": "__cf_bm=3852871f6e8f02f410491f-1552383037-1800-Acq+ObfnSR8WRCVLvsYmprM61p3DayCFn9W12LhqPFpzKqVCUvi9oCxaYUhN9XfNgdEvZc3RTa79NxufrMv8aoU=; __cfduid=dc8d787704f9af702c80e98d213b61f1f1552383037", 
            "date": "Tue, 12 Mar 2019 09:30:37 GMT", 
            "expect_ct": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"", 
            "expires": "Sun, 25 Jan 1981 05:00:00 GMT", 
            "failed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "attributes": null, 
                    "backup": null, 
                    "body": null, 
                    "body_format": "raw", 
                    "client_cert": null, 
                    "client_key": null, 
                    "content": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "delimiter": null, 
                    "dest": null, 
                    "directory_mode": null, 
                    "follow": false, 
                    "follow_redirects": "safe", 
                    "force": false, 
                    "force_basic_auth": false, 
                    "group": null, 
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                        "X-Auth-Email": "myemail@gmail.com", 
                        "X-Auth-Key": "jvnnf345mnbhfgj5"
                    }, 
                    "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
                    "method": "GET", 
                    "mode": null, 
                    "owner": null, 
                    "regexp": null, 
                    "remote_src": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "return_content": false, 
                    "selevel": null, 
                    "serole": null, 
                    "setype": null, 
                    "seuser": null, 
                    "src": null, 
                    "status_code": [
                        200
                    ], 
                    "timeout": 30, 
                    "unsafe_writes": null, 
                    "url": "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myzoneid/dns_records?page=1&per_page=1&type=A", 
                    "url_password": null, 
                    "url_username": null, 
                    "use_proxy": true, 
                    "validate_certs": true
                }
            }, 
            "item": 1, 
            "json": {
                "errors": [], 
                "messages": [], 
                "result": [
                    {
                        "content": "x.x.x.x", 
                        "created_on": "2018-01-22T05:00:45.020352Z", 
                        "id": "f5bc1d3ce029b0ffd6e21b617c1140a3", 
                        "locked": false, 
                        "meta": {
                            "auto_added": false, 
                            "managed_by_apps": false, 
                            "managed_by_argo_tunnel": false
                        }, 
                        "modified_on": "2018-01-22T05:00:45.020352Z", 
                        "name": "a.example.com", 
                        "proxiable": true, 
                        "proxied": false, 
                        "ttl": 1, 
                        "type": "A", 
                        "zone_id": "6c5f85f74db5f8af73a", 
                        "zone_name": "example.com"
                    }
                ], 
                "result_info": {
                    "count": 1, 
                    "page": 1, 
                    "per_page": 1, 
                    "total_count": 138, 
                    "total_pages": 138
                }, 
                "success": true
            }, 
            "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", 
            "pragma": "no-cache", 
            "redirected": false, 
            "served_in_seconds": "0.053", 
            "server": "cloudflare", 
            "set_cookie": "__cfduid=dc8d787704f1f1552383037; expires=Wed, 11-Mar-20 09:30:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.cloudflare.com; HttpOnly, __cf_bm=3852871f6e8f0ff5ed65d01db10ee402f410491f-137-1800-Acq+ObfnSR8WRCVLvsYmprM61p3DayCFn9W12LhqPFpzKqVCUvi9o12-Mar-19 10:00:37 GMT; domain=.cloudflare.com; HttpOnly", 
            "status": 200, 
            "strict_transport_security": "max-age=15780000; includeSubDomains", 
            "transfer_encoding": "chunked", 
            "url": "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/myzoneid/dns_records?page=1&per_page=1&type=A", 
            "vary": "Accept-Encoding", 
            "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", 
            "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN", 
            "x_ssl_protocol": "TLSv1.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Now using the above json output, I'm trying to capture the `total_pages` value. Following is my ansible task:

```
- name: Displaying the gathered records...
      debug:
        var: cloudflare_records.results.result_info.total_pages
```

But receiving below error:

```
VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

I tried with the `json_query` method as well but did not work for me.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is an array, so you need to get the first record of it which is `results[0]`. Please try

```
- name: Displaying the gathered records...
      debug:
        var: cloudflare_records.results.0.json.result_info.total_pages
```

or maybe `cloudflare_records.results.0.result_info.total_pages`

I prefer using debug-msg instead of debug-var when parsing json:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cloudflare_records.results.0.json.result_info.total_pages }}"
```

And if you have more than one result:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.json.result_info.total_pages }}"
  with_items: cloudflare_records.results
```